# How can I use an array defined in one JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, atlassian-ui

I have written the following code:

```
var json = result;
AJS.log("JSON Data Print")
AJS.log(json)

var treeData = [];
json_arr.push(json);
/*for(var x in json){
    json_arr.push(json[x]);
}*/
AJS.log("Copying JSON Data in to an array")
AJS.log(treeData)
```

Now I want `treeData` to be available in a different JS file. How can it be done?

Comment: If the code you showed is not in a function, then treeData IS now available to any JS file loaded after this file

Comment: @mplungjan: No it's not in a function still it is not available.

Comment: Works for me http://plungjan.name/SO/testinclude.html

Comment: @user2900150 not even within a `jQuery.ready()` function?

Comment: @Alex: How can I use that here?

Comment: You forget to mention this is Atlassian specific code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window` object so that it will be available globally. It will attach it as the property of global.

```
window.treeData = treeData
```

Comment: `var` should be creating the identifier in the global namespace already (assuming it's not inside a function)

Comment: Which `var treeData = [];` does all on its own if not in a function. Only need is the file defining `var treeData = [];` has to load before the one using it

Comment: @PaulS.: I keep getting this error, ReferenceError: treeData is not defined
 
var json_arr = []
var json_arr = treeData;

Comment: @mplungjan: file was not getting loaded and AJS does not allow to define a global outside of scope. Thanks.

Comment: That is of course the missing information which I improved by tagging Atlassian in your question. Perhaps you would like to improve your question with more specific scope?